# Printing in a class python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with trying to print the stats of the player in a class function. When I run it, it doesn't print.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, dmg, lvl, inventory, speed):
       self.name = name
       self.hp = hp
       self.dmg = dmg
       self.lvl = lvl
       self.inventory = inventory
       self.speed = speed

    def printStats(self):
       return("Health: " + self.hp + ", Attack Damage: " + self.dmg + ", Level: " + self.lvl + ", Speed: " + self.speed)

link = Player("Link", 10, 3, 1, {}, 3)
link.printStats
```

Comment: You don't call the function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print stats, you must *print* the stats.

```
def printStats(self):
    print("Health: " + ...)
```

You also need to actually *call* the function (notice the trailing parenthesis):

```
link.printStats()
```

A somewhat more pythonic solution would be to modify what gets printed when you print the object. You can do that by defining the method `__str__`. Then, just pass your object to the print command.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, dmg, lvl, inventory, speed):
       self.name = name
       self.hp = hp
       self.dmg = dmg
       self.lvl = lvl
       self.inventory = inventory
       self.speed = speed

    def __str__(self):
        return "Health: %s Attack Damage: %s Level: %s Speed: %s" % (self.hp, self.dmg, self.lvl, self.speed)

link = Player("Link", 10, 3, 1, {}, 3)
print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what version of python you are running in you'll need to do this

**for python 2.7**

```
    print link.printStats()
```

**for python 3.x**

```
    print(link.printStats())
```

Comment: unless you actually _call_ the function, nothing is going to get printed or returned.

Comment: @VarunTewari Yes, but that's not what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use `__repr__(self)` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr):

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, dmg, lvl, inventory, speed):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.speed = speed

    def __repr__(self):
         return("Health: " + self.hp + ", Attack Damage: " + self.dmg + ", Level: " + self.lvl + ", Speed: " + self.speed)


link = Player("Link", 10, 3, 1, {}, 3)
print link
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program in IDLE or the REPL, python automatically prints the return value of the function. So replace this:

```
def printStats(self):
    return("Health: " + ...)
```

with this:

```
def printStats(self):
    print("Health: " + ...)
```

You also failed to actually call the function (i.e. run).

```
link.printStats
```

simply says "Ok, find me the printStats function from link."

You didn't run it, you simply retrieved it.

Try this instead:

```
link.printStats()
```

BTW, python convention says that you should not use CamelCase lettering for functions. Use name_with_underscores instead.